# How do we add Multiple onclick event in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across one scenario that the onclick button is already been used

but at the same time i need to add one more event to to add history.push(),

I was working on sidebar component using material UI

so  need to customize few things I added the code

```
 const menuItems = [
 {
 text: 'Home',
 icon: HomeIcon,
 onClick: () => history.push("/"),
 },
 {
 text: 'Log In',
 icon: MailIcon,
 onClick: () => history.push("/login"),
 },
 {
 text: 'Sign Up',
 icon: HomeIcon,
 onClick: () => history.push("/signup"),
 },
 ];

 ...

<List>
{menuItems.map(({ text, icon: Icon, onClick}, index) => (
<ListItem
 button
 onClick={
 item === menus[2]
 ? handleSubMenu1Click
 : handleSubMenu2Click
  }
 >
  <ListItemIcon>
    <Icon />
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText primary={text} />
</ListItem>
))}
</List>
```

I tried something Like this

```
const menuItems = [
{
text: 'Home',
icon: HomeIcon,
to: "/",
},
{
text: 'Log In',
icon: MailIcon,
to:"/login",
},


<ListItem element={Link} to={item.to} button key={text}>
```

If we have submenu and also need to navigate across what would be the best Approach

Comment: either separate it with `;` `() => {oneFunction(); otherFunction()}` or wrap those 2 functions into function somewhere else and use that single function.

Comment: Something Like this

onClick={() => { item === menus[2] ? handleSubMenu1Click() : handleSubMenu2Click(); //console.log("my second function") }}

Comment: Yea, this should work I think.

Comment: But both will be called at the same time how will it get differentiated  between onclick submenu items and Router

Comment: Do you *need* two functions to be called at the same time, or have you a separate use case for click handlers in sub-menu items? It's unclear what exactly you are asking for help with since @MalwareMoon's comment would satisfy "How do we add Multiple onclick event in react.js" and you now are asking a different question.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, MalwareMoon is right,
After thinking I got the other question, but I haven't changed any questions yet
also my description at the bottom says 
If we have submenu and also need to navigate across what would be the best approach

Comment: @DrewReese How do we add separate use cases for both the submenu and a link?
this is a comment I am not going to change the question

Comment: What exactly are the separate use cases? Are the menu items not "links" to other pages?

Comment: I have a router at the app component which has signin component once authenticated I am moving to home page (wrapped up with protected route and there are allowedroles in that) this sidebar is with in home component if you look at my menu items how do I add these to the router? And the menu items has sub menu items

Comment: Yes Menuitems are not linked to other pages

Comment: If I'm just misunderstanding your question and code example, I'm sorry, but what other use case or logic do you need beyond `onClick: () => history.push("/"),` that isn't just simply something like `onClick: () => { /* other logic */; history.push("/"); },`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Event Bubbling to attach a single `onClick` handler to your `<List>` component instead of attaching multiple handlers to each `<ListItem>` as described here https://blog.logrocket.com/event-bubbling-capturing-react/.

In your handler function, you'll get a `SyntheticEvent` object whose `target` property will contain a reference to the clicked item, which you can use to determine what actions to take next.

**See this sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-sea-998zvl?file=/src/App.js

**However, from your code I infer you're just trying to create a navigation menu with links, and for that, you may just want to use `react-router-dom`'s `<Link>` component instead as shown in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-diffie-putb4f?file=/src/Nav.js**

Comment: Thank you for your time, it worked fine for me.

I have add another codesandbox similar one but I have used Router for that Have a look

and also if you get any chance to answer the question you can do that.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75987812/how-do-we-add-the-roles-to-the-nested-menuitems-sidebar-using-mui-react