# How do we add the roles to the nested menuItems sidebar using MUI -React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, material-ui, react-router

I am working on SideBar with nestedMeuItems, I have created  nested menu items separately and trying to add Roles to it

I have created a Router that is protected(// Unauthenticated users redirected to log-in route)

Also I have created AllowedRoles component to check the role while authentication

I have created a Sandbox for the same

[NestedSideBar-CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nesteddrawer-forked-1zw6mo?file=/src/App.js)

I  have not added the AllowedRoles component in the codesandbox the code is right below

```
 AllowedRoles.jsx

 import React from "react";
 import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
 const AllowedRoles= ({ roles = [], user, redirectTarget }) => {
 return !roles.length || roles.includes(user?.role)
 ? <Outlet />
 : <Navigate to={redirectTarget} replace />;
 };

  export default AllowedRoles
```

How do we add the roles for the nested items and their parent

Roles is an array of strings

If the parent menu is not able to get the role children cannot have access to it(hide)

if the parent has access and any one of the child menus has the same role then we can show the role based on one